# Java username and password login from array

Tags: java, arrays, authentication

Ok. I am making a piece of software for administration use on a computer. Enabling people to log in and do stuff dependong on their clearance. What i have so far is an array system of all users with ther username, password and clearance. What i want to be able to do is from a java swing window(which i have already programmed in) and compare username and password from that window to all the arrays and check for a match. any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks. My code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[]args){
    WindowLogin.openWindow();
}
}

public class Database {
public static String[] userAdmin = {"admin","admin","10"}; //Username password clearance
public static String[] userAlexander = {"Alexander","1234","1"}; //Same stuff here
}


import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class WindowLogin {
public static void openWindow(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Login");
    JTextField userName = new JTextField(20);
    JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
    JPanel info = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1,5,5));
    JPanel lnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1,5,5));
    JButton lnButton = new JButton("Log in");
    info.add(userName);
    info.add(password);
    lnPanel.add(lnButton);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.add(info);
    f.add(lnPanel);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java username and password login using arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725532/java-username-and-password-login-using-arrays)

Comment: Never ask the same question again because your old one got closed, review the old one and edit it.

Comment: @LionC : and i was wondering where did my comment go

Comment: @LionC i thought my old one was deleted permanently. i am noob to stackoverflow. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can achieve this.

```
String inputUserName = userName.getText();  //assign the user's input username
String inputPassword = password.getText();  //assign the user's input password

if(inputUserName.equals(userAdmin[0]) && inputPassword.equals(userAdmin[1])){
     System.out.println("Welcome Admin!");
}else if(inputUserName.equals(userAlexander [0]) && inputPassword.equals(userAlexander[1])){
     System.out.println("Welcome Alexander!");
}else{
     System.out.println("Unauthorized access");
}
```

On a different note, it is recommended that you create a User type to bundle the user-related information instead of using arrays.

Comment: Do you know of any way to prevent me from writing an if for each user.

Comment: @AlexanderHansen He says it: you bundle the information together in an object. Then throw those objects in a map. And to have it generic per user: if(usernameMap.contains(inputUserName)){.......}else{ print "unknown users"}

Comment: @jdmaguire's approach is good. If you don't want introduce a User object or a map, here is another way but it's a hard to maintain.

Put the arrays into another array.

`String[][] users = {userAdmin, userAlexander };`

Iterate over this array.

`for(String[] user: users){ if(inputUserName.equals(user[0] && inputPassword.equals(user[1]))) Sysout("Welcome") userFound = true; break;    }  if(!userFound){sysout("Unauthorized access")} `

Answer (score 1):

First, create object user

```
class User{
String username;
String password;
boolean isAdmin;

public User(String username, String password,boolean isAdmin){
this.username=username;
this.password=password;
this.isAdmin=isAdmin;
}
//setters and getters;
}
```

second, place your users not in list, but in map `Map<String,User> userMap` where key will be username, so when sb will log to the system,

```
public int logIn(String username, String password)
{
User user = userMap.get(username);
if (user==null
{
//No User with given username, return error code 1;
return 1;
}

if (password==user.getPassword().equals(password))
{
//password correct, error code - no error
return 0;

}
//password incorrect return error code 2
return 2

}
```

now all what we need is to init your `database`

```
class Database {
Map<String,User> userMap = new HashMap();

{
User admin = new User("admin","admin",true);
User alex= new User("Alexander","1234",false);
userMap.put(admin.getName(),admin);
userMap.put(alex.getName(),alex);
}
}
```